# Zero-pad a number in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am customizing an SSRS report, using an existing DataSource and DataSet.  I can't edit the DataSet definition (no permissions and I'm not going to get it), so I have to work with the data provided.  My problem is that some of the data is a bit garbled.  I'm attempting to group columns on an "Iteration" text column, but it contains data like:

```
Iteration 01
...
Iteration 09
Iteration 1
Iteration 10
Iteration 11
....
Pending Scope
```

The "Iteration 1" field is in the middle and is really messing me up.  How can I move this to the beginning of the set, or ideally merge it with Iteration 01?  I can't do it in SQL, and it's not a trivial "number format", so I can't just apply a format to it.

How can group & display the data above with the numbers properly zero-padded on the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to do this, but which is best depends on the details of your incoming data. If the sample in the question is fairly complete then I would put some embedded code into the report:

```
Function ParsedTitle(Title As String) as String
    Dim s as String
    s = TRIM(Right(Title,2))
    Dim num as Integer
    If Len(Title) < 2 Then
      return Title
    End If
    If Not Integer.TryParse(s, num) Then
        return Title
    End If
    Return TRIM(LEFT(Title, Len(Title)-2) ) + " " + num.ToString("00")

End Function
```

(This was only lightly tested.)

Then set the expression in a field to be:

```
=Code.ParsedTitle(Fields!Title.Value)
```

Comment: Cursory testing shows this works.  I actually ended up taking a somewhat similar approach, but using 2 calculated fields.  Since I know the text will be either "Iteration ##" or "Pending Scope", I just used MID to find the appropriate bit of text. In the second, I did something along the lines of "Iteration " & LEFT("000", LEN([first column]) & [first column].